# Python in VS Code

Tags: python-3.x, visual-studio-code

I'm trying to use Python 3.9 in VS Code. Consider following project folder structure:

```
C:\Project_folder\
                  app1\modules\some_module1.py
                       \some1.py
                  app2\modules\some_module2.py
                      \some2.py
```

If I tried to run the code of some2.py, in which:

```
import app1.modules.some_module1 as some_module2

**other python stuff**
```

It raise the error that app1 is uknown module. Even if,

```
"cwd": "${workspaceFolder}"
```

is in **launch.json**. When I tried to run:

```
import os
print(os.getcwd())
import app1.modules.some_module1 as some_module2

**other python stuff**
```

It returns me:

```
> C:\Project_folder
```

and raise the error of app1 module. What is wrong in this case? Why it can't see another directories?

Comment: Can you add the exact error you are getting? you can try adding "\_\_init__.py" files to the directories you are importing from. They don't need any content they just let python know that the directory should be considered a package

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you debugging your python file? In that case, you should use the following in launch.json file:

```json
"cwd": "${fileDirname}"
```

If you are running the python file using the run button in VS Code, then you need to set `python.terminal.executeInFileDir` to true in `setting.json`. You can do this by in settings in VS Code, by searching for `python.terminal.executeInFileDir` and set it to true, or simply paste this in the setting.json file

```
    "python.terminal.executeInFileDir": true,
```